# Is it possible to make the error message an object in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

The problem I have is that when i send the error message to the front end, it's a string with multiple errors `Validation failed: username: Please enter a username, password: Please enter a password`. I have tried to make the error message into an object, but it gives me this error: `TypeError: msg.replace is not a function`, How can I make the custom error messages objects?

```
 const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, {username: "Please enter a username"}],
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, {password: "Please enter a password"}],
      minLength: [8, {password: "The minimum password length is 8"}],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: What's the full error message, i.e. what comes after `msg.replace is not a function`?

Comment: Here is the full error message: `TypeError: msg.replace is not a function`. @norie

Comment: why do you want the error message to be an object?

Comment: So that I can use it in the frontend. Now if I get an error message, it looks like this: `Validation failed: username: Please enter a username, password: Please enter a password`, and it's a string. @DanielA.White